# (Python) Getting error when trying to scan range of ports for one IP address at a time

Tags: python, sockets, ip, port

I am attempting to scan a range of ports specified by the user for one IP address at a time until the fourth octet reaches 255. However, I am running into an error that my variable named 'count' is not defined although I am defining it to =1 so the program runs through every IP address such as 53.234.12.1, 53.234.12.2, 53.234.12.3, etc.

This is what I am trying to have displayed in the interpreter after all is said and done:
[End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blVf1.png)

Here is my code:

```
import socket

server = 'google.com'


startPort = int(input("Enter started port number to scan: "))
endPort = int(input("Enter ending port number to scan: "))
threeOctet = str(input("Enter the first three octets of an IP to scan: "))
countFullIP = threeOctet + "." + str(count)
count = 1

for countFullIP in range(0,256):
    for count in range (startPort,endPort):
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((server,countFullIP))
            print('IP',countFullIP)
        except:
            print('IP is invalid')
        try:
             print('Port',count,'is open')
        except:
             print('Port',count,'is closed')
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: countFullIP initially takes <str> '127.0.0.1'. Then as you have added a for loop where countFullIP takes <int> ranging from 0 to 256. Hope you doing what you indented for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace two lines

```
countFullIP = threeOctet + "." + str(count)
count = 1
```

to

```
count = 1
countFullIP = threeOctet + "." + str(count)
```

As you can see count is referenced before its assignment.

Updating the code upon additional requirement mentioned in comments.

```
import socket

server = 'google.com'

startPort = int(input("Enter started port number to scan: "))
endPort = int(input("Enter ending port number to scan: "))
threeOctet = str(input("Enter the first three octets of an IP to scan: "))

for count in range(0,256):
    countFullIP = threeOctet + "." + str(count)
    for count in range (startPort,endPort):
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((server, countFullIP))
            print('IP',countFullIP)
        except:
            print('IP is invalid', countFullIP)
        try:
             print('Port',count,'is open')
        except:
             print('Port',count,'is closed')
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I no longer get an error for an undefined variable. However, there is one last issue, which is that the IP addresses are not displaying. I suspect that I need to build my IP using string concatenation after I loop through each IP address, although I thought I did this with the countFullIP variable but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @czium24 You may want to update your code as per your one last issue of not displaying IP. This code would display now.

Comment: The except part of the loop that is catching the error is being displayed, or in other words, the interpreter thinks the IP address is not valid and is technically displaying an error along with every port specified in the range being opened which does not seem likely. I added count = 1 before the loops to avoid an undefined variable error.